# how to use useRef from outside of the component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

what i am trying to achieve that i made a react custom component for an input field looks like this in a seperate folder with name input.js

```
export function Input({id,type,label,name}) {
  return (
    <div className="form_container">
      <input type={type} id={id} className="form__input" name={name} autoComplete="" placeholder=" " />
        <label htmlFor="email" className="form__label">{label}</label>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and i used it inside my contact.js file which i want to use multiple times like this

```
 const fname = useRef(null);
 <form action="" onSubmit={sendEmail}>
     <Input ref={fname} id='inputName' type="text" name="fname" label="Name"  />
 <button type='submit'> Submit </button>
 </form>
const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(fname.current.value);
}
```

but i am getting this error while trying to refresh the page and i cannot access the input to get the value of it

```
react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
```

Answer (score 1):

only the old class components can be given refs natively.
use need useImperativeHandle hook combined with forwardRef
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle

Comment: i am trying to get the value so i can pass it to another nested component but its not working , i always get an error , i can only use focus() method